# Individual Bernoulli distributions from Discrete Uniform

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution, uniform-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Perhaps a silly question, but:

Let's say I want to randomly pick a number between 1-5, so that each number is equally likely to be picked. In other words, the number I pick is discrete Unif{1,5}.

Would this be equivalent to saying the distribution of picking each number is Bernoulli(0.2)?

Comment: Yes, marginally, but no jointly, that is the five indicators are not independent...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **marginally** what you say is correct, but lack of independence means that this will not hold jointly.

If $X_i$ is the number of times the number $i$ is drawn, then jointly $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5)$ will have a *multinomial distribution* with parameters $(n=1, p_i=1/5, i=1,2,3,4,5)$.